# Mongodb ubdate on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, mongodb

I installed MongoDB on live VPS to write logs. The server is running on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS and Mongodb version is 2.0.3. I want to upgrade to latest version (2.0.5) but I want to upgrade only MongoDB. I made test on my desktop with apt-get upgrade and everything is OK after the upgrade. However on my VPS I prefer to update just MongoDB. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Here is a up to date guide as of March 2013 http://www.lancejian.com/2012/03/12/install-nodejs-in-ubuntu-1004.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming that MongoDB is available in a configured apt repository. You can upgrade only certain packages by listing them in an install command, like this:

```
apt-get install mongodb
```

(You should however be keeping your server up to date with packages in the `lucid-security` repository though.)

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I tried `apt-get install mongodb-10gen` but I get message that I already have the newest version which is strange since my version is **2.0.3** and the current version is **2.0.5** . The same happens with `apt-get install mongodb`

Comment: What repository are you using for the MongoDB packages? Did you run `apt-get update` before trying this?

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you accepted mgorven's answer because running `apt-get update` resolved your issue.  To make it clear for anyone else, to get the latest releases of MongoDB on an apt based system, follow the instructions here:

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Ubuntu+and+Debian+packages

The relevant line to add to your sources list for Ubuntu 10.04 LTS is:

```
deb http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart dist 10gen
```

Then (after importing the key and running an apt-get update), you should install using:

```
sudo apt-get install mongodb-10gen
```

If you install just using "mongodb" you will get a very old release from the 10.04 repositories instead (1.6.x if I remember correctly).

Once the 10gen package is installed, `sudo apt-get update` followed by `sudo apt-get upgrade` will take care of installing new versions for you.

Comment: Yes, I decided to run `apt-get update` and then `apt-get upgrade` and this resolved the issue. Thanks :)